Android TV 14 with APK - Error : INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE
I will explain my problem ! I installed a version of Android TV 14 CustomROM on my Raspberry Pi 5.
I cannot install a 'private' application .apk (not available on the Google Play Store) downloadable via an application repository (eg: APKMirror). Here is the error:

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE: Reconliation failed ...: Reconcile failed: Package has no signatures that match in shared user android.uid.system; ignoring!]

I think this application was signed with private certificates and for specific devices and the version of Android TV 14 (CustomROM - Unofficial) that I am using was signed by different certificates (but I don't have this certificates) which logically poses an incompatibility problem. Tell me if I'm wrong?
Can you help me and tell me what I can do ?
Thank you very much for your valuable help !

If the sharedUserId="android.uid.system" is not essential:
Remove it from your AndroidManifest.xml:

Rebuild and sign your APK with your developer keys.

Hi @AbdulQuddusMozumder, I don't know about Android development ... :( I don't have 'developer keys' and how 'Rebuild and sign your APK' ? Is there a process ? Thank's

The app you try to install is a system app built and signed for a different system. As Abdul suggested Our can try to modify Android manifest.xml file by decompiling the APK  e.g. with apktool, remove the sharedUserId part and recompile and resign the app. Not sure if it will work afterwards. How to use apktool and resign an APK you can read on a lot if sites.
